# Applying a torque that rotates the object to a desired vector

Tags: rotation, physics

Having an object with a forward vector f, and a vector v being the "desired" forward vector how can one calculate a torque (x,y,z) that will ultimately rotate the object so that f = v.

Comment: Just taking the unit cross product of f*v should give you the required unit torque vector. As far as the magnitude is concerned you will need a time varying torque to get it to stop at the final position otherwise your vector will just continually accelerate

Comment: This seems to work, if you write this as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: However i seem to have problems scaling it properly as you stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the unit cross product of f*v should give you the required unit torque vector.

As far as the magnitude is concerned you will need a time varying torque to get it to stop at the final position otherwise your vector will just continually accelerate. Some sort of [triangle function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) parametrized by time should work. (or any sinusoidal function really)